# adding geojson layer results in a grey background which covers base map

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Steps to reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Go to https://virgilxw.github.io/Singapore_Election_1955/
Click on the top right button on the map
click on "data"
click on "constituencies"
Expected behavior
Polygons should overlay base map

Current behavior
base map covered by grey-colored layer

Leaflet version:1.51.1
Browser (with version):
OS/Platform (with version):
Additional context
``

```
// Default base Map
map.addLayer(LayerOSM);

// Add geojson
var Layer1955Wards = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/wards1955.geojson");

// Styled Layer Control
var baseMaps = [
    {
        groupName: "Base Maps",
        expanded: true,
        layers: {
            "OneMap": LayerOneMapSG_Default,
            "OSM": LayerOSM
        }
    }];

var overlays = [
    {
        groupName: "data",
        expaned: "true",
        layers: {
            "Constituencies": Layer1955Wards
        }
    },
    {
        groupName: "Map Overlays",
        expanded: "true",
        layers: {
            "1953 Topological": Layer1953Topo,
            "1953 Aerial Photographs": Layer1953Aerial
        }
            }];

var styledLayerControlOptions = {
    container_width: "300px",
    container_maxHeight: "350px",
    group_maxHeight: "80px",
    exclusive: false
};

var styledLayerControl = L.Control.styledLayerControl(baseMaps, overlays, styledLayerControlOptions);
map.addControl(styledLayerControl, overlays);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polygon layer has a white background which covers base maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375327/polygon-layer-has-a-white-background-which-covers-base-maps)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe, except in case I check/add the "1953 Aerial Photographs" layer. In that case, the map/tiles sometimes _seem_ to disappear (leaving the grey background visible). They appear back as soon as I uncheck/remove that aerial photos layer.